# Default function values and variables in memory

Tags: python-3.x

I came across the following code:

```
def f(x,l=[]):
for i in range(x):
    l.append(i*i)
print(l) 

f(2)
f(3,[3,2,1])
f(3)
```

which returns:

```
[0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

my question is this:

Why, in the third function call `f(3)`, is l not overwritten with `l=[]` in `def (f(x,l=[])` and then return `[0,1,4]`? What is going on here??

When I do this instead, things work as expected..:

```
l=[]
[l.append(i*i) for i in range(2)]
print(l)
l=[1, 2, 3]
[l.append(i*i) for i in range(3)]
print(l)
l=[]
[l.append(i*i) for i in range(3)]
print(l)
```

which prints:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 4]
```

I know the answer has to do with the way python stores data in memory, but I can't wrap my head around this one, even after exploring with `id(l)` (which prints out the same ID of l for both `f(2)` and `f(3)` but a different ID for `f(3, [3,2,1])`.

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Check if my answer makes sense to you. You should not assign default values to mutable function arguments like list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to have a local variable `lst` inside the function which takes care of the operation you are doing inside the function, rather than operating on a variable you are passing like so.

```
def f(x,lst=None):
    lst = lst or []
    for i in range(x):
        lst.append(i*i)
    print(lst)

f(2)
f(3,[3,2,1])
f(3)
```

Which gives you output as

```
[0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 4]
```

The reason the previous approach doesn't work is because when a mutable value as list or dictionary is detected in a default value for an argument, they are evaluated only once at function definition time, which means that modifying the default value of the argument will affect all subsequent calls of the function.
But in my changed function, I am making a new local variable to operate on the list, which is a copy of the argument passed, so we don't get this issue here.